# Windows 2012 SERVER - No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a WebAPI 2 using EF6 on my local machine and it works perfectly.
When I PUBLISH the solution and upload it to the server, I get the following error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   Database.FooModel.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

**Note:**
I see many posts about fixing the development machine but my problem is not that. My problem lies when I upload the code to the Windows 2012 server.

**Question:**
How do you ensure that the **SERVER** gets the proper settings when uploading a EF6 solution?
I already updated the server to DotNet 4.5.1, what else should I install on the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

=======================================
**SOLUTION:**
Unfortunately, I had to restart a new application and quickly copy the files and that solved the problem. Now the server runs perfectly. If I look at the Published files (prior and after), I see a newer "EntityFramework.dll" file version and a new "EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" file on the bin directory. I also noticed that "Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll and Microsoft.Data.OData.dll" are not on the new version.

Not sure this info can help ..but at least we know that we can create a new application and that works !!!

Comment: +1 for the info that helped me.  In my case, EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll was not getting published.  Once I got this file onto the server, everything worked!

Comment: Thanks both of you - I was also missing EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.  Removing and re-adding the references seemed to fix it.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but not able to resolve it as per the steps mentioned above. Is there any other solution? I am getting this problem at a specific server and its working fine on another server. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Copy "EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" in bin directory on server or add it to the solution as reference and republish.